# How do yo record gun-movement foley?

Tags: foley

hello everybody.I ask for the first time.

By a recent movie and game of gun-movement、
How does everybody make a sound?
What kind of material do you do foley?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking specific sounds like slide racks, mag inserts, and such, you should actually record a real weapon if you have the time and budget. Or, buy someone else's gun foley FX: Chuck Russom had a nice gun foley pack for sale, and *many* others do, too, on both the indie and large-scale commercial sides. Faster, cheaper...and safer.

If you mean generic weapon movements, my understanding is that the general clackety-clack of weapon movement is a trope of cinema and not at all realistic - which is OK. But this is *sound design*, right? Part of the joy and challenge is to just look and listen for what else would fit the bill. For example, I've made science fiction weapon movement sounds with an [old-style apple corer](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-107835/stock-photo-a-stainless-steel-apple-peeler-corer.html), with great results.

Comment: That apple corer looks like a twisted torture device.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what joe said, on no budget in a pinch I've purchased a staple gun ($15) and processed it to make it work as hand gun movement, drops, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use a metal three-hole punch for lots of my wouldn't-happen-in-real-life weapons movement. As NoiseJockey said, for the specific operating sounds try to use the genuine article.

Answer (score 1):

Staplers (particularly if you can find an older one that's all metal) and wine bottle cork screws (the kind that has the arms you pull down after screwing into the cork) work great for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"my wouldn't-happen-in-real-life weapons movement" <- thats a great term!

I've used a car jack for exactly this - many years ago I owned a Ford Escort and its jack was great as it had enough weight.... A long time after I sold the car I bought a jack from one - handy prop for a foley room!

Comment: Thanks! And, great idea about the car jack. Those Escort jacks do sound pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pickup a library Franks just released a new collection:
http://www.therecordist.com/firearm-foley-hd-pro-sfx

Answer (score 0):

Metal wine bottle openers work good too - good more more of the smaller ticky-tacky subtleties of a pistol.  One of the old-style ones like this: http://gotsole.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/wine-opener1.jpg

Might have to play with it to get the right kind of sound.

Oops, Shaun beat me too it... so in that case, I concur!

Answer (score 0):

I would add this for holstering and unholstering weapons: pulling different clothes out of a backpack until you're satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded the sound of a collapsible metal framed kids garden chair and that gives a reasonably movie-sounding gun handling effect (when processed with a bit of EQ and pitch changing).

Answer (score 0):

i have used this site effectively for foley before in filmmaking: http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=gun  Just remember to give credit where is due.